# Docker-in-Docker doesn't work on self hosted linux runner

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm having trouble utilizing docker commands in af self hosted linux runner.

Reading the docs it should work more or less out of the box, just like when using atlassians own runners.

however, when running a docker command i get an error:

```
+ docker version
bash: docker: command not found
```

The relevant part of the pipelines yml file:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    'master':
      - step:
          name: 'step1'
          script:
            - docker version //this works
          services:
            - docker
      - step:
          name: 'step2'
          runs-on:
            - self.hosted
            - linux
          script:
            - docker version //this fails
          services:
            - docker
```

The only self hosted runner specific mentions of docker commands, is the new addition of using custom images to run the docker daemon inside a runner, but as i understand it, running the default should work, also on selfhosted runners.

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-your-runner-in-bitbucket-pipelines-yml#Custom-docker-in-docker-image

Am i missing that should be done when starting the runner, or is this not supported (yet) ?

I've asked the same question on atlassians community: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Selfhosted-runner-cannot-use-docker-commands/qaq-p/2186491#M87567
Will answer this question, if i get an answer from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was answered on Atlassians community, and the solution was to use the image docker:dind as the Docker image.

You can add the "definitions:" configuration below to your YAML file above the "pipelines:" config.

```
definitions:
   services:
      docker:
         image: docker:dind

pipelines:
  branches:
    'master':
          - step:
...
```